# PHP mbstring extension isn't enabled? (WampServer)

Tags: error-message, php, server

I'm using WampServer Version 3.0.4 64bit on Windows 10 to run a local dev site. It's been working fine for a few weeks, and I last opened the site about 5 days ago. Today when I go to my site, I'm getting this error:

> Craft CMS requires the PHP multibyte string extension in order to run.
>   Please talk to your host/IT department about enabling it on your
>   server.

I checked my PHP extensions menu in Wamp, and there is a check mark next to php_mbstring, so it seems to be enabled.

When I go to localhost in my browser to view my Wamp home page, I see the following error:

> *** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: - should be: c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/bin/php.ini or
>   c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.19/phpforapache.ini

I don't know if this is new, but I haven't changed anything in my wamp configuration files since the site was working.

Full Wamp configuration, in case it's helpful:
[image: Here's my wamp setup]

I'm fairly new to both Wamp and Craft, so not sure where the problem lies. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these things go, after I posted my question, I clicked "Refresh" in the Wamp menu and now my site works. I'm not sure what changed, especially since I already restarted the entire program several times, but all's well that ends well.

Configuration after refreshing:
[image: new wamp config]

Comment: Update: I think maybe I didn't shut down Wamp properly the previous time? I just got the error again, and I think that may be what happened.